# Silverlight child data retrieved in query but not available in OnLoadCompleted method

Tags: silverlight, linq, relational

I have Silverlight 4 RIA service app with a class Sprinkler which has a child collection Depths. Sprinkler and Depth are two tables in an SQL database where one Sprinkler has many Depths.

I call the query from a class, thus:

```
Context.GetRunsForSelectedSprinkler(currentSprinkler.CurrentSprinkler, OnLoadListCompleted, null);
```

and the method where I access results of query in same class is:

```
private void OnLoadListCompleted(InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Sprinkler>> invOp)
{

   IEnumerable<Sprinkler> testRuns = invOp.Value;

}
```

My query in DomainService is

```
[Invoke]

public IEnumerable<Sprinkler> GetRunsForSelectedSprinkler(string selectedSprinkler)
{

//            this.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

   var sprinklers = (this.ObjectContext.Sprinklers.Include("Depths").Where(c =>  c.Sprinkler1 == selectedSprinkler));

   return sprinklers;

}
```

What I find using debug is that inside this query GetRunsForSelectedSprinkler the Depths collection for each sprinkler in sprinklers is populated properly. However, in the method OnLoadListCompleted which receives the result of this query, that although the sprinkler data from the Sprinkler table is there, the Depths child collection that was populated by the query (because of Include("Depths")) is now not there and Depths is null. Somehow this Depths collection has got lost during the return process.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I have Google extensively and I think the query is right, but I can't find anything about failure to return the child collection.

I have tried putting [Include] for the Depths collection in the metadata but that has no effect. I have also tried setting `this.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` 
and not, but it has no effect. 
The query is executed correctly but the result is not returned correctly to OnLoadListCompleted and it is somehow losing the related child data.

Answer (score 0):

If one keeps guessing at the right keywords eventually one can Google the right answer, and I can now answer my own question. I followed advice on this page:

http://silverlightguy.com/2010/07/23/trick-for-solving-wcf-ria-services-issue/

which solved my problem and the child collection was returned properly.

It seems that this is a known issue in RIA services, even if it is hard to discover. And I also found this page:

[InvokeOperation entities become null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448534/invokeoperation-entities-become-null)

and tried to make mine a query instead of Invoke but hadn't finished solving it this way before finding the above method worked, so don't know if this works.

I also found this page mentioning the problem, but haven't followed up on it.

[Silverlight 4 LoadOperation returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116510/silverlight-4-loadoperation-returns-null)

Thanks to those people who posted above.